# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src' in Jyputer notebook

Tags: python, module, src

I have the following structure in my GitHub repo (which I cloned):

```
src
  __init__.py
  |-- data_manipulation
      |-- __init__.py
      |-- processing.py
  preprocessing.py
README.md
ws-notebook.ipynb
```

In my ws-notebook.ipynb I am trying to import

```
from src.preprocessing import create_data
```

And I am getting the error:

```
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'"
```

I am working in VSCode in a conda environment

```
- Python 3.11.4
- conda 23.7.4
- xgboost 2.0.0
```

I used

```
import sys
import os
```

and the results were:

```
print(sys.path)
```

```
[
'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code', 'c:\\Users\\User\\anaconda3\\envs\\xgboost-env\\python311.zip',
...,
]
```

```
print(os.getcwd())
```

```
['C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code']
```

I think the problem is that I cloned my GitHub repo in my D: drive and somehow the paths are messed up and cannot align.
After that I have no clue how to solve it.

Comment: How exactly are you running this code?  My guess is that you're running it in such a way that the current directory is **not** the same directory where the ipynb file lives.

Comment: Use this code to show the current directory: `import os; print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: @JohnGordon  You were right, I had to figure out a solution with the paths to import my module.  Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be how you open the notebook. You seem to be using vscode. Try opening vscode then from the top left click File -> Open Folder (or ctrl + k), then open the project folder.

Also, You can add the path of you project dir, be using `sys.path.insert`

```py
proj_path = "enter/the/full/path/to/your/project"
# or the next line to get the path on its own
proj_path = os.path.abspath('')
sys.path.insert(1, proj_path)
```

Comment: I used what you recommended:
```
proj_path = "C:\\Users\\the\\full\\path\\to\\your\\project"
sys.path.insert(1, proj_path)
```

But it is not a permanent solution, Though many thanks

Comment: I think the problem could be how you open the notebook. You seem to be using vscode. Try opening vscode then from the top left click File -> Open Folder (or ctrl + k), then open the project folder. Tell me if this works so that I add it to the answer.

Comment: you were right I managed to open the folder ( File -> Open Folder) and it worked as it should. Many thanks